# Calculate day of the week error

Tags: java

I have wrote this program and the output isn't working. Could you please help me identify where the error is?
I have to use this code not any other from the internet,
as we have to construct it from what we understood from the lesson.
I am using jgrasp.

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g samooras.java
```

the error I get is

```
samooras.java:25: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String[]
                  -2*(year/100))%7+7)%7+1;
                                       ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class samooras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] dayoftheweek = {"Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"};
        int year = input.nextInt();
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        dayoftheweek = ((day +
                         (13 * ((month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 1) / 5
                         + year % 100
                         + year % 100 / 4
                         + year / 400
                         - 2 * (year / 100)) % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
        System.out.println("the day of the week is: " + dayoftheweek);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your program inputs from console ? Also details about the error :)

Comment: What do you mean `its not working`?

Comment: ----jGRASP exec: javac -g samooras.java

samooras.java:25: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String[]
                  -2*(year/100))%7+7)%7+1;
                                       ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

Comment: Please edit your question and add those details :)

Comment: Hi @AmrMixy if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using that formula to get the day of the week from the array you created, in which you would do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class samooras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] dayoftheweekArray = {"Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"};
        int year = input.nextInt();
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        int dayoftheweekNumber = ((day + 
                                   (13 * ((month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 1) / 5
                                   + year % 100
                                   + year % 100 / 4
                                   + year / 400
                                   - 2 * (year / 100)) % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
        String dayoftheweek = dayoftheweekArray[dayoftheweekNumber]; 
        System.out.println("the day of the week is: " + dayoftheweek);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did we use  String dayoftheweek = dayoftheweekArray[dayoftheweekNumber];

Comment: If you're asking about the variable names, those are just arbitrary.  But your formula gives you a number, 0-6 (I assume), which represents the day of the week. From there you need to select that day from the array. Know that if your formula gives you a result of 1-7, you'll need to do `dayoftheweekArray[dayoftheweekNumber+1];

Comment: based on your formula, you calculated the day index which is an integer, using that index you have to look up corresponding string from array, hence `array[index]`

Comment: @AmrMixy if it worked, feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define:

```
String[] dayoftheweek={"Sat","Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri"};
```

dayoftheweek is an array (that what the [] means). An array contains multiple values of the same type (in this case String). To access an element of the array we use an index(for example dayoftheweek[0] is the String "Sat").

So when you say:

```
dayoftheweek=((day+ ...
```

you are computing the index of the day of week in your "dayoftheweek" array.

First of all you can't use the same name so, you should have something like:

```
int dayIndex = ((day+ ...
```

Once you have the index, you need to apply it to the array in order to get the actual day of week String:

```
System.out.println("the day of the week is: " + dayoftheweek[dayIndex]);
```